# How to convert a.b to ['a']['b'] in python

Tags: python, string

How can I change the below string as mentioned below in Python:

Input1 : a.b
output1 : ['a']['b']

Input2: a.b.c.d.e
output2: ['a']['b']['c']['d']['e']

Comment: Look up string methods in python, namely split()

Answer (score 2):

```
''.join(f"['{part}']" for part in s.split('.'))
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I am using it as a key to get value from a dictionary , then I am getting KeyError Exception.
['a']['b'] is the key here, but when I tried to access the value of this key, It is reading it as "['a']['b']"

Any Solution please?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
newStr = "['" + oldStr.replace(".", "']['") + "']"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be more flexible to use a regex replace for this.

```py
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('(\w+)\.?', r"['\1']", 'a.b')
"['a']['b']"
```

You could change the character set from `\w` to `[a-zA-Z]` if you didn't want to include numbers in the names.